# Stripe buy now button taking additional parameters

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I have a Buy Now button from stripe on my HTML page as follows;

```
<div>

    Qty: <input type="text" name="qty" />

    <script async
        src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/buy-button.js">
    </script>

    <stripe-buy-button
        buy-button-id="buy_btn_klsfjhskdfhjskdfhsldkCK"
        publishable-key="pk_live_klsdhflkasdhfkajsldhfkjashdflkjahygayblrlcuaneiadjleidhauehk
    >
    </stripe-buy-button>

</div>
```

Is there a way to pass the `QTY` to the button to modify the amount by the customer?

I cant seem to find anywhere to add additional parameters to the button.

Comment: Are you using payment links?

Comment: @kopz ... I believe so yes

Comment: In that case, I don't think you can change the quantity since payment links are simple pre-defined links to buy something. You could make separate links for packs of 2 or 3 otherwise you will need to integrate Stripe Checkout.

Comment: Buy button can't pre-set the quantity. However, you may set the Payment Link to `Let customers adjust quantity`, so that the customer can adjust the quantity in the Payment Link later.